# How to access Parity node's mempool with web3.py?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, web3.py, python

I'm running a Parity node with `parity --jsonrpc-api all`, then connecting to it in python3 with `w3 = web3.Web3(web3.HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))`.

I can call `print(w3.eth.getBlock('latest'))` and see the results fine, but I cannot call `w3.txpool.inspect` - I get `ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'Method not found'}`

It seems that web3.py only knows about Geth mempool functions?
How can I call Parity's `parity_allTransactionHashes` method in python (https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module.html#parity_alltransactionhashes)?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t as the method isn’t implemented. You would have to call the raw Json rpc endpoint directly from your script.